# Unity3D app using Android device camera with auto-focus issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working with a `Unity3D` app for Augmented Reality that, when deployed to an Android device, uses the camera to perform character recognition.

The tablet’s camera **auto**-**focus** no longer works though, so the scanning (character recognition) is really bad.

I am working on a number of hypotheses to find the cause; the first one being the fact that the `Camera` class was [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) in `API level 21`.

When I run the following command in my `Terminal`, I get `7.0` because my SDK is new from April 2017.

```
$ adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
```

The following snippet exists in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in my `Unity3D` project. If the cause is the old camera class no longer being valid, how should I modify this code in the `AppManifest` file to fix the problem?

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion='0x00020000'/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true"/>
```